# Counting the number of open files for each user?

Tags: linux, bash, lsof

I am looking for a command that would list me number of open files for each user, sorted descending.

For example `lsof -u postgres | wc -` would list them only for the postgres user, but I do want to see on which user I may loose handlers.

Note: some question may apply to PIDs instead of user names, but still, I am looking for a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

I ran Warren Lavallee's script, and found it difficult to interpret.

Instead, I extended the original script to step through all the users to give the following:-

```
for f in $(sed</etc/passwd 's/:.*$//g'); do ( echo -n $f ' '; lsof -u $f 2>/dev/null | wc -l ); done | grep -v ' 0$'
```

This works fine on Ubuntu 14.04. The final `grep` removes the zero entries, as a lot of the users will not have active processes. You can also add `| sort -rnk 2` to the end of the command to sort into descending file count order.

You will need to be in a root shell to make sure you can see the files from all users.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to pipe's, how about this:

lsof |  perl -pe 's/\s\s+/ /g'  | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -v ^USER | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn

I tested this on MacOS 10.10.2 (Yosemite), OEL 6.6, and Ubuntu 10.04.01.